# How to prevent fetching specific table on db connection using SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, columnstore

Using columnstore table in MSSQL Server requires rebuilding index online, which takes hours but is acceptable. Problem is when SQL alchemy used in python API sometimes is auto-reconnecting to DB and hangs because it couldn't reflect columnstore table which is 'busy' too long. I've tried to use:

```
 `with flask_app.app_context():
      metadata = MetaData()
      metadata.reflect(db.engine, only=[table_names_without_columnstore])
      base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
      base.prepare(db.engine, reflect=True)
      db._results_tables = base.classes
 `
```

but it still hangs. Any ideas how to prevent SQL Alchemy from fetching that table during init?

Comment: Does the table metadata need to be re-generated from the database each time, or are they going to be stable over long periods of time?

Comment: rather stable, db schema update is done by alembic app. once per month

Comment: Then just *put your schema into Python code*, or at the very least pickle the metadata object and restore from that.

Comment: is Metadata serializable, so I could put it out of container which will be destroyed during redeployment?

Comment: SQLAlchemy metadata objects can be fully serialised with pickle.

Comment: See notes on the [expression serializer extension](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/serializer.html): *Regular `pickle.loads()`/`dumps()` can be used to fully dump any `MetaData` object, typically one which was reflected from an existing database at some previous point in time.*